# Applying the command "expr/.rule", to find the expansion of Cos[a+b]

Tags: simplifying-expressions, series-expansion, trigonometry, homework

how can i find the expansion of Cos[a+b], using the expression g[f[{a,b}]].So i am specified to use one shot replacement to get the expansion by replacing the argument of the expression given. I tried something but i couldn't think of what to do next ?

```
expr = g[f[{a, b}]]
rule = {List[a, b] -> Cos[a + b]}
expr/.rule
```

Comment: It is quite unclear what you mean.

Comment: @MarcoB these are parts of the bigger problems, have solved 20 so far, some by the help of this useful site, isnt this site for getting the questions that are unclear , answered?

Comment: Are you talking about this `rule = {List[a, b] -> Cos[a + b] // TrigExpand}`

Comment: also `rule = List -> Composition[Cos, Plus]` will turn `{a,b}` into `Cos[a+b]`

Comment: @BillWatts , no actually i defined rule as to be the replacement rule , the rule shows ( what will i be replacing with what from the expression) . i could use different commands but its specified to just using the one shot rule to get the expansion.

Comment: @HaneenHussam it is better for those who will attempt an answer to provide some form of a desired outcome. In this way, the end goal is clear, while the path to the answer is unclear. As in, you know you want b, and this is clear, but you have a, and how to get from a to b, this is unclear. That said, do you strictly want to turn the `List` in the argument into `Cos[a+b]`?

Comment: @CA Trevillian , Yes I understand what you are trying to tell. I am sure, there are much clearer ways of evaluating the regarding expressions but in the question that i have requires to turn the list into total of the arguments!

Comment: It is still very much not clear what you want to do. Do you have to use the `g[f[...]]` form? Are you only replacing the list? Why even use `g` or `f`? If you strictly must start with your `expr`, then use `/.` with some set of rules, Bob has already solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
expr = g[f[{a, b}]];
```

Presumably, the intent is to use rules to replace `f` and `g`

```
expr /. {f -> Total, g -> Cos}

(* Cos[a + b] *)

expr /. {f -> (Apply[Plus, #] &), g -> Cos}

(* Cos[a + b] *)
```

To get an expansion you need a third function so either `f` or `g` must be replaced by a [`Composition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html)

```
expr /. {f -> Total, g -> Composition[TrigExpand, Cos]}

(* Cos[a] Cos[b] - Sin[a] Sin[b] *)

expr /. {f -> (Apply[Plus, #] &), g -> Composition[TrigExpand, Cos]}

(* Cos[a] Cos[b] - Sin[a] Sin[b] *)

expr /. {f -> Composition[Cos, Total], g -> TrigExpand}

(* Cos[a] Cos[b] - Sin[a] Sin[b] *)

expr /. {f -> Composition[Cos, (Apply[Plus, #] &)], g -> TrigExpand}

(* Cos[a] Cos[b] - Sin[a] Sin[b] *)
```